# Trying to display Attribute data in .geojson file uploaded to android_app

Tags: android-studio, gis, mapbox-android

I begun following tutorials provided in mapbox website on how to display cartographic data in json format, and I could display maps without any problem.

The challenge I'm facing now is that I can't display the `attribute data` in these maps.

As recommended, I edited the question and here is the code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.TRAFFIC_DAY, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                        VectorSource vectorSource = new VectorSource(
                                "Supports-source", "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/anis82.b8l0y56t.json?access_token="
                                + getString(R.string.access_token)
                        );
                        style.addSource(vectorSource);
                        CircleLayer circleLayer = new CircleLayer("Supports-style", "Supports-source");
                        circleLayer.setSourceLayer("SUPPORTS_HTA-BT-9n49es");
                        style.addLayer(circleLayer);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
        final PointF pixel = mapboxMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(point);
        List<Feature> features = mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel,"SUPPORTS_HTA-BT-9n49es");
        if (features.size() > 0) {
            Feature feature = features.get(0);
            if (feature.properties() != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : feature.properties().entrySet()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", String.format("%s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: include the code in the question - (not as an image)

Comment: you can edit the question ^

Comment: I have edited the question and you recommended. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Can you say more about what your end goal is? What do you mean by `attribute data`? Are the circles displaying on the map when you run the code above? You're missing some sort of data? Any Mapbox-related messages in your logcat (look for `Mbgl` in the logcat)?

When you say `attribute data`, do you you mean that nothing gets printed with `Log.d("TAG", String.format("%s = %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));` when you click on the map? That might be because you're querying the wrong layer.

You have `List<Feature> features = mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel,"SUPPORTS_HTA-BT-9n49es");`. You're querying `"SUPPORTS_HTA-BT-9n49es"`, but that's a layer within your vector tiles. You should be querying 
the `"Supports-style"` circle layer, because that's the actual layer being rendered on the map. It's a bit confusing, I know.

If the circles aren't even being displayed:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-a-vector-tile-source/ is a straightforward example of using a `VectorSource`.

You're appending an access token to a URI as you build a `VectorSource` object. Looks the same as what's described at https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset-id/#use-a-tileset-id-to-request-tilesets-directly

Instead of that, try doing the URI syntax seen at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/VectorSourceActivity.java#L50 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/53651ce092d1dab1cbc32aefe3d95558f1b6f692/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/labs/BaseballSprayChartActivity.java#L139.

Comment: Dear Langsmith, thanks a lot for your reply. As you know what is displayed on the map are electric poles of the electric network located in Tunisia. Every circle contains data related to the pole's technical specifications. So my objectif is to display such a popup when i click to each circle so I can read its specs. these data are uploaded fom a geojson file.

Comment: Ok, what happens when you do  `List<Feature> features = mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel,"Supports-style");` ? 

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/ is helpful for popups. However, there's also https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/pull/314 (see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/issues/1329)

Comment: Also, don't forget to add `mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MainActivity.this)`. I'd add it after the `style.addLayer(circleLayer);` line **inside** of the `onStyleLoaded()` callback section.

Comment: Dear Langsmith, excuse for not responding in time. What I really want is displaying data included in the vector files, which represent attribute data of these points (electric poles), through a popup which is displayed once I click in these points.

Comment: Ok, well all of my suggestions and links above, still apply to that use case. What issue(s) are you currently running into? Something not appearing on the map?